# Can we change the font of the "new responses" in meta.scifi so that it is readable?

Tags: bug, design, meta

This isn't necessarily a "feature request", but concerns more of an inconvenience. I just noticed that when you have a "new response", i.e. one that you haven't looked at before, in the meta site in your profile page, that the background to the "new response" in order to highlight/distinguish from the "older" responses, is white. Which is a problem...as the text, is also white.

Is it possible to change this to something else? Maybe just invert the normal background/foreground colors for the highlighting so that the contrast still makes reading possible?

Comment: Similar? http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1816/title-for-updated-favorited-question-unreadable

Comment: @Xantec Yes, I am sure that is the exact same issue actually. (I VTCd this now, though if it gets closed I may bump your post up by appending this issue to it as well if that is O.K.)

Comment: @NominSim Is that other meta question and this one about the exact same item?  If not, then they're not duplicates.  That other question mentions it's explicitly about the list of questions under 'favorites', but this question doesn't.

Comment: @Keen Well, it seems like the issue they are talking about is the same, in that anything on the user profile that is "highlighted", means that the background becomes white, and the white text then makes it unreadable. (I suspect this happens for every "highlighted" section on the meta user profile). So while the questions talk about 'favorites' **and** 'responses' I think they address the same underlying problem.

Comment: @NominSim The problem with that is the person fixing the bug needs to know each specific area that is affected, so they can verify that every instance of the bug gets fixed.  Otherwise, you might end up with just favorites or just responses being fixed, while the other is left broken.  If they're the same underlying issue, yes, fixing one will fix both.  If they're not the same underlying issue, then we need to document each specific issue separately.

Comment: @Keen I was thinking about just kind of "merging" the questions together, so that the person doing the fixing only has to look in one area. It looks like the bug will affect any highlighted section of the profile page. I definitely agree with you though that both problems should be documented somewhere.

Comment: Just a follow up to this, there seems to be *several* places where this same font problem shows up. The [Markdown Editing Help](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) is another.

Comment: I just bugged Jin on this. He says "eek. i'll fix", so watch this space :)

Answer (score 5):

Just to catalog the other places the highlight text exhibits the same problem, [in the comments](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting), you mentioned the [Markdown Help page](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#bare-urls):

> [image: example of Markdown Help higlight]

But it also happens [when a FAQ section is highlighted](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask):

> [image: example of FAQ section highlight]

In the help text at the top of pages in the new review system:

> [image: Review system help text]

And in the [stats summary](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/review-beta/close/stats) for the new review system:

> [image: Stats summary for review]